# parsing string in Groovy?

Tags: parsing, groovy

I am new to Groovy and I am trying to parse header from my REST service response. 
The string is below:

> [http://localhost:4545/third-party-web?code=IVJZw1]

I am trying to code `IVJZw1`.

It is easy and I hope I get help quick.

Azou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the square brakets are stripped off, it's just an URL.  You could try something like this:

```
import java.net.*
def str = '[http://localhost:4545/third-party-web?code=IVJZw1]'
def url = new URL(str.replaceFirst('^\\[', '').replaceFirst(']$', ''))
def paramMap = url.query.split('&').collectEntries { param -> 
    param.split('=').collect { URLDecoder.decode(it) }
}
assert paramMap['code'] == 'IVJZw1'
```

Comment: I am using this in a groovy script in soapui and i am getting the following error:

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceFirst() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [^\[, ]

Comment: Seems like a lot of work to get whatever is after the equals minus the trailing bracket.

Comment: @user713927 From what you've said you actually have a List of Strings and not a single String as your question suggests. Please be careful when asking questions that you actually know what data you are dealing with. atatylor's answer will work, you just don't need to try and strip off "[" and "]" now. But you will have to get the first (and only) String out of the List before you can work with it.

Comment: thanks you For your help, I will be more careful next time, been a long day getting my web service up and running and this last bit just had me stumpe. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, but it's quite a general answer; it can be used to extract any value or values from the parameters of a URL. I added an answer with a more direct approach :P

Comment: @epidemian Yep, it's general, but given the apparent skillset of the OP, I'd opt for simple first, and general later, especially when it's not accompanied with an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

If you want something quick and dirty, you can use a regex:

```
def str = '[http://localhost:4545/third-party-web?code=IVJZw1]'
def code = (str =~ /code=(\w*)/)[0][1]
assert code == 'IVJZw1'
```

There i assumed that the "code" parameter is composed of alphanumeric characters (`\w`).

However, if you find yourself extracting parameter values from URLs very often, this solution will get awfully dirty quite soon. Something like ataylor [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543332/581845) will probably be more appropriate, specially if you can extract the logic of getting the URL parameters on a separate function. Maybe even a method on the URL class itself :D

```
import java.net.*

// Retrieves the query parameters of a URL a Map.
URL.metaClass.getQueryParams = { ->
    delegate.query.split('&').collectEntries { param -> 
        param.split('=').collect { URLDecoder.decode(it) }
    }.asImmutable()
}

// Then that method can be used directly on URLs :)
def str = '[http://localhost:4545/third-party-web?code=IVJZw1]'
def code = new URL(str[1..-2]).queryParams.code
assert code == 'IVJZw1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Commons Http Client is a HTTP agent implementation in java supporting client-side authentication, HTTP state management and HTTP connection management. This requires the libraries httpclient-4.1.2.jar, httpcore-4.1.2.jar, httpmime-4.1.2.jar, httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar, commons-codec.jar and commons-logging-1.1.1.jar to be in classpath. The following example shows how to parse URI Query parameters.

API

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

is a well known library that you can use

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/something.html?one=11111&two=22222&three=33333";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
  System.out.println(param.getName() + " : " + param.getValue());
}
```

Outputs

> one : 11111
>
> two : 22222
>
> three : 33333